# Track Changes button grayed out excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel workbook (.xlsx) in which I want to track changes. However track changes button is grayed out. I tried searching, but couldn't find any solution.

This workbook contains 5 worksheets, so I tried moving (copying) each sheet to a new workbook, and I found that when I copy one particular sheet, track changes option gets grayed out in the new workbook. So there is something in this sheet which is causing track changes to be grayed out.

[image: Attached is the screenshot]
[Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFCBV.png)

Comment: Is the spreadsheet password protected?

Comment: No, its not password protected.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found answer to the solution. Apparently the track changes option is disabled (grayed out) if any of the sheet contains a table. There was one table in one of the sheets of the workbook. When I changed the table back to range, I was able to track changes.

Comment: The same issue and solution exists in Excel 2016.

Comment: To convert table to range >> right click on table and choose from context menu Table > Convert to range. [More](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-an-excel-table-to-a-range-of-data-0b326ff1-1764-4ebe-84ea-786265d41c77)